# Tomcat 9: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers

Java 11, Tomcat 9, sometimes I get

```
tomcat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

I read that it can be because of a lot of things, how can I isolate the cause of this error? I do have HTTPS and I do call with HTTPS, it doesn't happen everytime, not sure which API (I have several) is causing this issue.

I also read that it might because of max.... settings but without the problematic API/header I don't know which API to check, assuming this is the problem...

Any hint/tip will help here, thanks